# How to enter a special character as a password character in C#

Tags: c#

How do I enter a unicode character (it needs to be the equivalent of ascii character 254, a solid square centered box) as the password character in a textbox?

I need to do this in code, for example textbox.passwordchar = ????????

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

The same way you enter any other character.
C# source files can contain Unicode characters in identifiers and strings.

You can also use the escape sequence `"\uxxxx"` to use a Unicode character by (hex) codepoint.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [TestBox.PasswordChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.passwordchar.aspx) property. Assuming you want `UNICODE` character [BLACK SQUARE (U+25A0)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25a0/index.htm), either do:

```
yourTextBox.PasswordChar = '■';
```

Or:

```
yourTextBox.PasswordChar = '\u25a0';
```

Answer (score 1):

textBox_Name.PasswordChar='■';

When you want to use any of the unicode char simply Press ALT & then ascii value of that key while pressing ALT key

**e.g.**

> ■ = ALT+254
>
> ♪ = ALT+269
>
> A = ALT+65
>
> a = ALT+97

**NOTE:** numeric keys must be pressed from NumPad

Answer (score 0):

```
tb.PasswordChar = (char)254;
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be able to just assign a constant Unicode character, as described in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664669%28VS.71%29.aspx)...

Answer (score 0):

this.tePassword.Properties.PasswordChar = (char)254; results in a character that looks similar to a b - it's definitely not ascii 254.